# Восприятие большоего непрерывного куска памяти в куче как трёхмерный массив

Tags: c++, c++20

Стоит задача аллоцировать кусок памяти в куче (примерно на 100 мб), обработать его и передать дальше как указатель и размер (после чего память можно освободить). Дело в том, что данные в нём, по факту трёхмерный массив `uint8_t` и на этапе обработки было бы очень удобно иметь интерфейс трёхмерного массива `arr[x][y][z]`. Не могу подобрать подходящий для этого инструмент. Вектор, векторов, векторов по понятным причинам не подходит. Аллоцировать трёхмерный массив на `std::unique_ptr` тоже.

Comment: Вот вам целых два варианта - https://ideone.com/fod4Jd  Пояснять не надо?

Comment: @Harry Пока не получается зайти на ideone. Не под vpn, вообще никак. Как зайду, отпишусь.

Answer (score 2):

Код с https://ideone.com/fod4Jd:

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    unsigned char * p = new unsigned char [3*5*2];
 
    unsigned char (&a)[3][5][2] = *(unsigned char (*)[3][5][2])p;
 
    a[1][2][1] = 121;
    a[0][3][0] =  30;
 
    cout << (int)p[1*5*2 + 2*2 + 1] << endl;
    cout << (int)p[0*5*2 + 3*2 + 0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Это UB. Это больше формальность чем практическая проблема, но все равно. :s

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно! Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Rivand Вы же сказали, что размер неизвестен во время компиляции?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, вы правы. Вчера ночью по запарке подумал, что я могу писать произвольные числа при объявлении ссылки. Сейчас сел за код и осознал проблему. Чуть позже попробую написать врапер с оператором [], как вы советовали.

Comment: Ну, тогда просто добавьте на время работы двумерный массив указателей, чтобы через них можно было работать с выделенной памятью соответствующим образом...

Answer (score 1):

Если размер массива известен во время компиляции, то `std::make_unique<std::array<...>>()`:

```
auto x = std::make_unique<std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 20>, 30>>();
```

Если неизвестен, то только делать свой класс с перегруженным `operator[]`.

Comment: Нет. К сожалению во время компиляции неизвестен =(, потому и в куче. Иначе обошёлся бы обычным трёхмерным массивом.

Comment: @Rivand Даже будь размер фиксированный, 100 мб переполнили бы стек.